# can't save to mongodb properly on nodejs server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a simple html form, when the user submits it, it gets sent to the server with an ajax request. The server is supposed to take the form data and store it in a mongodb document. I am using a nodejs server with express framework and mongoose to work with mongodb.

When I create a test account, it says the account is created and I get re-directed to the tiles.html page and I get a console log saying "User created!", so good so far, but when I go back to the home-page and create an account again with the same password, I'm not getting an error saying the password is already taken, it's creating an account again and taking me to the tiles.html page. Maybe I don't have Mongodb configured correctly, I didn't install the hot-fix (I'm on windows7), could this be the problem or is it in the code?

I start my server by executing the following command

```
mongod --dbpath /Rockstar22/data
```

(I don't know if this is the correct way to do it)

This is the server side code (excluding the require statements)

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myappdatabase');
console.log("connected to mongo...");
var User = require('./users');
```

where users.js is

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    age: Number, 
    gender: Boolean
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

I have body-parser so

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

This is the code that deals with the form

```
app.post('/CAform', function(req, res){
var isAJAXreq = req.xhr;

if (isAJAXreq) {
    var username1 = req.body.username;
    var password1 = req.body.password;
    var age1 = req.body.age;
    var gender1 = req.body.gender;
    if (gender1 === "Male"){
        gender1 = true;
    } else {
        gender1 = false;
    }
    age1 = parseInt(age1);

    User.findOne({ password: password1 }, function(err, user) {
        if (user){
            res.send(
                {data:JSON.stringify({response: 'taken'})
            });
        }
        else {
            var newUser = User({
                username: username1,
                password: password1,
                age: age1,
                gender: gender1
            });

            newUser.save(function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;

                console.log('User created!');
            })

            res.send(
                {data:JSON.stringify({response: 'created'})
            });
        }
    });
}

});
```

and this is the client side code for submitting the form (whose id is createAccountForm)

```
$("#createAccountForm").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var username1 = $("#CAusername").val();
    var password1 = $("#CApassword").val();
    var passwordConfirm1 = $("#CApasswordConfirm").val();
    var age1 = $("#sel1").val();
    var gender1 = $("#sel2").val();

    var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
                username: username1,
                password: password1,
                age: age1,
                gender: gender1
            });

        $.ajax({
            url: "/CAform",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: jsonData, 
            timeout: 5000,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.response === "taken"){
                    $("#passConfirm").append("Password Already Taken");
                    return;
                } else {
                    location.href="/tiles.html"
                }

            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('process error');
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Change `password: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },` to `password: { type: String, required: true, index:{unique: true}` in order to create a unique index which mongoDB uses to prevent duplicate documents.

Comment: @snozza now it's not even creating the user, it's going right to the tiles page, how do I delete all existing documents in myappdatabase

Comment: go into the mongo shell, type `use myappdatabase` and then `db.dropDatabase()`. Also, I would suggest that you place the unique constraint on username rather than password

Comment: the thing is though, I check if the password exists before I save it so I shouldn't even need to set index:{unique: true}, and also, is that the correct way to start the database? (mongod --dbpath /Rockstar22/data)?